# Will my app be rejected if my app works as a content trade platform and uses Paypal?

Tags: ios, paypal, in-app-purchase

I would like to add a feature to my app that enables my app users to create digital content and sell them to each other through my app. I would like to use *PayPal* or other third party online payment solutions. Will my app be rejected? Please advise, thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple policies and not programming.

Answer (score 3):

It is totally legal and it will not be rejected from the app store on that basis. There are certain features that need to be added through in-app purchases, but the transactions are not handled through in-app purchases. Since, one person is buying from another person in the application, you will have to use PayPal or some other third party payment solution and Apple will be totally fine with it.

Infact, paypal has a seperate SDK for iOS Integration. You can access it here:

```
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Khawar. I have to mention that my app also charges a small amount handling fee. So I may be the co-seller of the digital content. And further more, this digital content can only use in my app. Do you know any app implements similar feature and accepted by App Store?

Comment: @Larry I don't think Apple would have any issue with you or your app users getting profits if the digital content is created by the seller in the application. You can send an email to their customer relations to get further details about this issue. Secondly, you can make the whole flow in a way that in-app purchases become impossible, so Apple will have no option but to select your process